# fs.fileReadSync not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the [webgl-heatmap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webgl-heatmap) package in my react application and it throws this error.Any way go solve this issue?

[image: react code]
[image: error image]

Comment: Browsers don't understand the node api file system, so using `fs` won't work. This a fork of the original that I'm assuming needs to be a part of a node build process [fork](https://github.com/vicapow/webgl-heatmap/blob/master/webgl-heatmap.js)/[original](https://github.com/pyalot/webgl-heatmap/blob/master/webgl-heatmap.js), but there are no instructions on how to implement it. You may want to consider taking a look at the original instead if you're not using a build system like webpack.

Comment: @Andy so best is i should build it webpack and then use the js file in my react application?
https://github.com/pyalot/webgl-heatmap this si the link to the one in the repository still trying to figure out how to implement the example.html concept in react but the js file can't be loaded into react so now looking for alternatives.